# Recursive core of coalition game

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Can someone please explain the recursive core concept possibly with an example?
http://arno.unimaas.nl/show.cgi?fid=5152

I don't understand how the recursion works.

Thank you

Comment: What part are you stuck with?

Comment: @LokiClock In the Definition 4 (Pessimistic) In the 2nd step it says it is going to define dominance of $k$ player game but seems to define dominance of $N$ player game in step 3 and in the last step how is that a $k$ player game has $N$ player core? because the core is $C_{-}(N,V)$

Comment: The link in your question does not work for me.